# How to add another column to this chart?

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

Here is the code to show the users ranking using amCharts Javascript library.

The code's output is something like this:

[image]

As you can see there are 6 users that are ranked from 1 to 6 all aligned to the left side of the page (The first group).

**Now the problem is I want to continue ranking users from 7 to 12 (Second group) and align them to the right side of the page.**

Something like this one :

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't handle this.

[Here is the code on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/pGMaQL?editors=1010)

And here is the Javascript code:

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);


var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
        "profileName": "John",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 6",
        "level": "6.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"

    }, {
        "profileName": "Sara",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 5",
        "level": "5.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Nima",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 4",
        "level": "4.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Max",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 3",
        "level": "3.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Megan",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 2",
        "level": "2.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Inna",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 1",
        "level": "1.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }  ];

// Chart A:

//create category axis for Names Column 
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "profileName";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = -100;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dy = -60;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis.labelsEnabled = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#4286f4");


//create category axis for Slogans Column 
var categoryAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "slogan";
categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis2.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12;

//create category level
var categoryAxis3 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis3.dataFields.category = "level";
categoryAxis3.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis3.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dx = 170;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 16;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#ccd3e0");


//create value axis for income and expenses
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;



valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 10;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;  
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 25;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.disabled = true;

//create columns
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryY = "profileName";
series.dataFields.valueX = "income";
series.name = "Income";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;


// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;
chart.paddingTop = 64;
chart.paddingBottom = -30;

// Add bullets
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.width = 120;
image.height = 120;
image.dy = 0;
image.dx = 100;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet";
image.tooltipText = series.columns.template.tooltipText;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

Html code:

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/core.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/charts.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <script src="Script.js"></script>
```

and CSS:

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 840px;
}

body {  
    margin: 40 100 100 20;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);   
 }
```

Any suggestions are extremely appreciated...

Comment: Why do you want to do this with amcharts. It OS possible with plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Technically, it's possible by assigning your series to different value axis and making them stack (https://www.amcharts.com/demos/vertically-stacked-axes-chart/). But I must agree with previous comment: using charts for this is kinda excessive. Would be easier to just have it in HTML.